# Integral of Trigonometric Identities

Tags: integration, trigonometry

$$\int(\sin(x))^3(\cos(2x))^2dx$$

I can write $$\sin^3(x)=\sin(x)(1-\cos^2(x)=\sin(x)-\sin(x)\cos^2(x)$$

for $$\cos^2(2x)=(1-\sin^2(x))^2=1-4\sin^2(x)+4\sin^4(x)$$
after simplifying the Trig identities i get:
$$\int(sin^3(x)-4sin^5(x)+4sin^7(x))dx$$

so i need to know how to go further :)

Comment: No, unfortunately there is no such way.

Comment: ok check it out now. I have simplified to bits but still cant integrate these trig bushy identities.

Comment: or using Reduction formula for Integrals is the only way out?

Comment: $\sin x = \dfrac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i}, \,\cos 2x = \dfrac{e^{2ix}+e^{-2ix}}{2}$ and then expand -- clearly works here.

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin: The OP seems to be a beginner, I doubt he has learned about the connection between complex exponentials and the trigonometric functions.

Comment: The best elementary method to evaluate integrals with both $\sin x$ and$\cos x$ is to write the integral in terms of $\int \cos x f(\sin x)dx$ or $\int \sin x f(\cos x)dx$. For $\int \cos x f(\sin x)dx$, by the substitution $u=\sin x$, we have $du=\cos x dx$ and finally converting the integral into form of $\int  f(\sin x)dx$. Similar for $\int \sin x f(\cos x)dx$ with use of substitution $u=\cos x$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note $f(x)=\sin^3 x \cos^2 2x$. You have

$$\cos 2x = 2 \cos^2 x -1$$
Hence

$$(\sin^3 x)(\cos^2 2x)=\sin x \sin^2 x (2 \cos^2 x -1)=\sin x (1- \cos^2 x) (2 \cos^2 x -1)$$

As $(\cos x)^\prime = -\sin x$, we get by expending the right hand side $$f(x)=-(\cos x)^\prime (- 2 \cos^4 x +3 \cos^2 x -1)$$ and finally

$$\int f(x)dx = \frac{2}{5} \cos^5 x - \cos^3 x + \cos x + a$$

Comment: can you make it a little more clear as how second last step, before i integrate.

Comment: I added some elements, not sure that is what you were looking for... However Sherlock Holmes should be able to investigate the clues!

Comment: what happens to the -(cosx)'? dissappears? sherlock is confused! That is my only Query

Comment: What is the derivative of $f^p$ knowing the one of $f$?

Comment: i thought we had to use the chain rule as -(cosx)' is multiplying the rest.
derivative of $$f^p = f''$$?

Comment: That's right! I used the chain rule.

Comment: could you still show me how to use the chain rule in this particular case. I am a very newbie and also curious! How can i use the chain rule formula when a f' is hanging around.

Comment: What is the derivative of $x \mapsto \cos^p x$ where $p$ is an integer? You have to apply the chain rule here.

Comment: can you now edit your answer and show the chain rule as i want to show it to a friend of mine. thnks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

take your integrand $$\sin^3 x-4\sin^5 x+4\sin^7 x $$ and factor the $\sin x$ so you get $$ \sin x\left(\sin^2 x-4\sin^4 x+4\sin^6 x\right) = \sin x\left( (1-\cos^2 x)-4(1-\cos^2 x)^2+4(1-\cos^2 x)^3  \right)$$

now make the substitution $$u = \cos x , \quad du = -\sin x \,dx $$ so you have $$\int\left( \sin^3 x-4\sin^5 x+4\sin^7 x \right)\, dx = -\int\left(1-u^2-4(1-u^2)^2+4(1-u^2)^3\right)\, du$$

Answer (score 1):

1. Odd powers are easy to integrate, substitution $u=\cos x$ will convert it into a polynomial.
2. Half-angle substitutions (or straight-up the universal trig substitution) can handle the even cases.
3. If the integral goes over a simple multiple of the period, there are special forms (involving Beta function, for instance).
4. If you really don't know what to do, you can always go into complex numbers, where all these are just exponentials, which are trivial to integrate. A lot of terms to process, of course, but that way, you don't have to remember all the multiple-angle formulas.

Answer (score 1):

The most elementary method is this: $\sin ^3 x = \sin x (1- \cos ^2 x)$ and $\cos ^2 2x = (2 \cos^2 x -1) ^2$. Substitute, do the multiplications, group together similar terms and split your result into integrals of the form $\int \sin x \cos ^n x \Bbb d x$ (preceded by various factors). Note now that $- \sin x = (\cos x)'$, so the previous integral becomes $- \int (\cos x)' \cos ^ n \Bbb d x = - \frac {\cos ^{n+1} x} {n+1}$. Add up all these integrals and that is it.

Answer (score 1):

$$\int\left(\sin^3(x)\cos^2(2x)\right)dx=$$
$$\int \left(\frac{7}{16}\sin(x)-\frac{5}{16}\sin(3x)+\frac{3}{16}\sin(5x)-\frac{1}{16}\sin(7x)\right)dx=$$

$$\int \frac{7}{16}\sin(x)dx-\int \frac{5}{16}\sin(3x)dx+\int \frac{3}{16}\sin(5x)dx-\int \frac{1}{16}\sin(7x)dx =$$

$$\frac{7}{16}\int \sin(x)dx-\frac{5}{16}\int \sin(3x)dx+\frac{3}{16}\int \sin(5x)dx-\frac{1}{16}\int \sin(7x)dx =$$

$$-\frac{7}{16}\cos(x)-\frac{5}{16}\left(-\frac{1}{3}\cos(3x)\right)+\frac{3}{16}\left(-\frac{1}{5}\cos(5x)\right)-\frac{1}{16}\left(-\frac{1}{7}\cos(7x)\right) =$$

$$-\frac{7}{16}\cos(x)+\frac{5}{48}\cos(3x)-\frac{3}{80}\cos(5x)+\frac{1}{112}\cos(7x)$$